# Passing Object with AngularJS $http.post to .Net asmx

Tags: .net, angularjs, vb.net, web-services, asmx

So I am trying to pass a javascript object from Angular $http.post to a .net web service. I have this working for another web method like so

```
var GetLeadTimeline = function($http,idLead){return $http.post('/admin/leads/LeadUpdates.asmx/GetLeadTimeline', {idLead: idLead});};
```

But the method just takes an integer as an id

I want to receive an object now.
I am getting a 500 error, can anyone point me in a direction to show what I am doing wrong?

Code in template

```
<button id="btnAddReminder" data-id="" data-name="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="AddNewReminder(l.idLead, l.FirstName + l.LastName)">
```

AngularJS - Function

```
$scope.AddNewReminder = function(idlead, name) {
            var dataObj = { 
                ReminderContent: name, 
                ReminderDT: $scope.Reminder.DateTime,
                idLead: idlead
            };
            var ReminderPromise = LeadsServiceTest.UpdateReminder($http,dataObj);
            ReminderPromise.then(function(response) {
                    //Do something
            });
        }
```

AngularJS - Service

```
 myLeadDashboard.factory('LeadsServiceTest',[function(){
        var UpdateReminder = function($http,dataObj){return $http.post('/admin/leads/LeadUpdates.asmx/AddReminder', dataObj);};
        return {
            UpdateReminder:UpdateReminder                
        };
    }]);
```

.Net Object Class

```
 Public Class ReminderFields
    Public ReminderContent As String = ""
    Public ReminderDT As String = ""
    Public idLead As Integer = 0
End Class
```

.Net Method

```
 <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True, XmlSerializeString:=False)>
Public Function AddReminder(ByVal value As ReminderFields) As UpdateResponse
    Dim response As New RemindersResponse
    Dim NewNotifcation As New Agent.Notifications
    NewNotifcation.Subject = value.ReminderContent
    NewNotifcation.TimeStamp = CDate(value.ReminderDT).ToUniversalTime.Subtract(#1/1/1970#).TotalSeconds
    NewNotifcation.idLead = value.idLead
    NewNotifcation.idNotification = 0
    NewNotifcation.Save()
    response.Success = True
    Return response
End Function
```

Comment: How can this be bumped back up? Should I set a bounty?

Comment: You use `$http.post` and your method states to use `HttpGet:=True`. What happens when you remove `HttpGet:=True` or set it to false?

Comment: I removed it, and was having issues with the object. I ended up just passing in data like.      <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False)>
    Public Function AddReminder(ReminderContent As String, ReminderDT As String, idLead As String) As UpdateResponse